# Differences and when to use SortedList<T>'s updateItemAt() or recalculatePositionOfItemAt() methods?

Tags: android

Question 1

I was looking at the example code on [this page](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/util/SortedListActivity.java) that uses SortedList with RecyclerView.

At line 127, after the CheckBox status changed, `recalculatePositionOfItemAt()` method was used. The javadocs for `SortedList<T>` says that `recalculatePositionOfItemAt()` is for adjusting item positions without triggering `onChanged()` callback. And `updateItemAt()` will call `onChanged()` and/or `onMoved()` if necessary.

In the case of the example code, the item's field `boolean mIsDone` changed. I thought `updateItemAt()` would be more appropriate here?

Question 2 (related)

I tried to play around to use `updateItemAt()` with a sorted list, but some times `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling` was triggered and I found lines 122-125, 152-154 in the example code helps to avoid the exception. I thought the checkbox checked status changing event can only happen when the user checks/unchecks the checkbox. Why are these lines necessary? Some times random tapping or scrolling events far away from the checkboxes can trigger the event?